# How can I join one below the other (not fusioning/merging data) 3 columns from 3 different tables in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, pentaho-spoon, spoon

On Pentaho - Spoon I want to select and join 3 columns which are fields related to Date and named differently, from 3 different tables (one field from each table), and join all the data in one single column that will be called Date. I tried to do it with a step but couldn't find it so I think the easiest way is to write the script. Any idea? I am lost...Thanks!!

I started with:
SELECT dbo.SCHOOL.Date, dbo.STUDENT.Year, dbo.EXAMS.Year
FROM dbo.SCHOOL, dbo.STUDENT, dbo.EXAMS

Answer (score 0):

use UNION not JOIN, if you want to merge data. If your all columns have the same data type (date).

```
SELECT Date, 'SchoolTable' FROM dbo.School
    UNION  
SELECT Year, 'StudentTable' FROM dbo.Student
    UNION
SELECT Year, 'ExamsTable' FROM dbo.Exams
```

or give more information about tables

Comment: Hi! thanks mate but it didn't help in my case, it says Year field is ambiguous and once I Run it it appears only 3 records lol. No clue, perhaps the problem is in the type of the fields

Comment: By the way, 'SchoolTable' is it just to clarify or would be needed in the scrip?

Comment: you can remove second fields (SchoolTable,..), it is just for showing the name of the table which related rows. If you get the ambiguous column name error (it's not related UNION, perhaps JOIN), set aliases for tables in your query and use it before field names. `SELECT s.Year FROM dbo.School AS s  ....`